# How can I see the information from a tooltip of a circle marker which is contained within a polygon which also has a tooltip

Tags: leaflet, tooltip, overlapping

I am very new to leaflet.

Below is my code where a polygon layer and a point layer are loaded from Geoserver through wfs service.

Each layer has a tooltip. When the two layers do not overlap the tooltips work as expected. When a point overlaps a polygon, in its position the tooltip of the polygon is shown. Unfortunately, for my purposes, when the two geometries overlap I want only the circle marker tooltip to be shown, that is exactly the opposite behavior than it is currently doing. It seems to be a kind of issue so impossible to solve for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
    <title>Example Leaflet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css">
  </head> 
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    html, body, #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var map = new L.Map('map');

var OSM = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);

var myRenderer = L.canvas({padding: 0.5});

var dataset = new L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://46.101.36.208:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=deep_map:point_tooltip_test&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson1&SrsName=EPSG:4326&MaxFeatures=200',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'getJson1',
  success: function(response) {
    WFSLayer1 = L.geoJson(response, {
      style: function(feature) {
        return {
          color: '#696969'
        };
      },
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            renderer: myRenderer
            });
        },
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        
        var popupText = '';
        
        if (feature.properties.NOMECOMUNE) {
            popupText += "<b>NOMECOMUNE: </b>" + feature.properties.NOMECOMUNE + "<br />";
        }
        
        if (feature.properties.CIVICO) {
            popupText += "<b>CIVICO: </b>" + feature.properties.CIVICO + "<br />";
        }
        
        layer.bindTooltip(popupText, {'sticky': true});
      }
    }).addTo(dataset);
    // map.fitBounds(WFSLayer1.getBounds());
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://46.101.36.208:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=deep_map:polygon_tooltip_test&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson2&SrsName=EPSG:4326&MaxFeatures=200',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'getJson2',
  success: function(response) {
    WFSLayer2 = L.geoJson(response, {
      style: function(feature) {
        return {
          stroke: true,
          fillOpacity: 0
        };
      },
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        var popupText = '';
        
        if (feature.properties.NOMECOMUNE) {
            popupText += "<b>NOMECOMUNE: </b>" + feature.properties.NOMECOMUNE + "<br />";
        }
        
        if (feature.properties.ZONA) {
            popupText += "<b>TIPO ZONA: </b>" + feature.properties.ZONA + "<br />";
        }
        
        if (feature.properties.DEN_FI) {
            popupText += "<b>AREA DI RISPETTO: </b>" + feature.properties.DEN_FI + "<br />";
        }
        
        if (feature.properties.TR_VINC) {
            popupText += "<b>TRATTO VINCOLATO: </b>" + feature.properties.TR_VINC + "<br />";
        }
        
        if (feature.properties.DESCRIZION) {
            popupText += "<b>CATEGORIA FORESTALE: </b>" + feature.properties.DESCRIZION + "<br />";
        }
        
        if (feature.properties.GIARDINI) {
            popupText += "<b>PRESENZA GIARDINI: </b>" + feature.properties.GIARDINI + "<br />";
        }
        
        if (feature.properties.STAB_INDUS) {
            popupText += "<b>STABILIMENTO A RISCHIO INCIDENTE GRAVE: </b>" + feature.properties.STAB_INDUS + "<br />";
        }
        
        if (feature.properties.CHANGETYPE) {
            popupText += "<b>VARIAZIONI: </b>" + feature.properties.CHANGETYPE + "<br />";
        }
        
        layer.bindTooltip(popupText, {'sticky': true});
      }
    }).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(WFSLayer2.getBounds());
  }
});

map.on('zoomend', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() < 16){
            map.removeLayer(dataset);
    }
    else {
            map.addLayer(dataset);
        }
});

var BaseMap = {
"Base map": map
};

L.control.layers(BaseMap).addTo(map);

    </script>
</html>
```

**What I tried**

I tried to create two explicit separate panes for each layer as follow:

```
map.createPane("polygonsPane");
map.createPane("pointsPane");
map.getPane('pointsPane').style.zIndex = 750;
map.getPane('polygonsPane').style.zIndex = 350;
```

Then I assigned each layer to its pane inside the `style` section.

For the polygon layer:

```
style: function(feature) {
        return {
          stroke: true,
          fillOpacity: 1,
          pane: "polygonsPane"
        };
      },
```

And for the point layer:

```
style: function(feature) {
        return {
          stroke: true,
          fillOpacity: 1,
          pane: "pointsPane"
        };
      },
```

With this, I was able to bring the points to the front and to make the tooltip work. Unfortunately, the tooltip for the polygon doesn't show anymore!

I'm very new to Leaflet. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I've been racking my brain trying to see what I'm missing. I would really appreciate it if anyone is able to give me a workaround.

Thank you very much.